# Selecting text in vb

Tags: vb.net

I want to select a word to another word in a text box in vb.net with everything between them highlighted.

an example is

> I went to the beach, had a pinic with my family and then went home at 6 o clock.

The starting word to be `had` and the end word being `home` and everything highlighted in between.

I have already used a little bit of code

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim a As String
    Dim b As String
    a = TextBox2.Text 'means what ever is in textbox2 string to the location where "a" is
    b = InStr(RichTextBox1.Text, a)
    If b Then
        RichTextBox1.Focus()
        RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = b - 1
        RichTextBox1.SelectionLength = Len(a)
```

but its not exactly what i want it to do.

Addition to this was using RegEx Function  as shown below

```
  'gets rid of the enter line break eg <enter> command no new lines
     Dim content As String = Replace(TextBox1.Text, Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10), Nothing)
    'searches for this tag in the brackets between ".*" will be the contents
    Dim Regex As New Regex("<div.*class=""answer_text"".*id=editorText"".*""")
    'Show the string 
    For Each M As Match In Regex.Matches(content)
    'This will get the values, there are 3 atm meta.name des and content
    Dim Description As String = M.Value.Split("""").GetValue(3)
    'displays the content in the label
    TextBox3.Text = "" & Description
    Next
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what would be inside `TextBox2`?

Comment: <div class="answer_text" id="editorText"> This will be in textbox 2. What im trying to do is parse out html but instead using the tags as the start and stopping points

Comment: @Dilocho working with start and end words for parsing html isn't good solution, better use something like htmlagilitypack or in worst case regex

Comment: @Vlad L I've investigated into these two types which I found very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

This will select everything between startWord and endWord excluding them both

```
Dim startWord As String = "had"
Dim endWord As String = "home"

Dim index As Integer = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(startWord)
richTextBox1.[Select](index + startWord.Length, richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(endWord) - index - startWord.Length)
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but it is hardcoded. I think OP is using it as an example and wants this behavior interactive, meaning the mouse decides the start and end words, not the code.

Comment: @ryrich looking on the OP code I don't think so. He is using the TextBox2.Text where the (probably) start word is defined and says nothing about the mouse

Comment: ok, I got it. Made an answer for OP which does the same thing, mimicking his button's subroutine, but making the selection inclusive instead of exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution involving two `TextBox` controls:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim a As String
        Dim b As String
        Dim index_a As Integer
        Dim index_b As Integer
        a = TextBox1.Text
        b = TextBox2.Text
        index_a = InStr(RichTextBox1.Text, a)
        index_b = InStr(RichTextBox1.Text, b)
        If index_a And index_b Then
            RichTextBox1.Focus()
            RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = index_a - 1
            RichTextBox1.SelectionLength = (index_b - index_a) + Len(b)
        End If
End Sub
```

`TextBox1` contains the first word, `TextBox2` contains the second word. When clicking the button, it will highlight from the first word to the end of the second word.